# d3.js transition is not working with property method

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, internet-explorer-11

I am learning d3.js. In the script below, ***selection.transition()*** does not seem working when ***selection.property()*** is chained, though it works when ***selection.property()*** is put in ***transition().each()***. Am I doing something wrong? Or, is this specifications of ***transition()***?

```
<input class="property_transition" type="checkbox">Property Transition Test</input><br>
<input class="property_transition" type="checkbox">Property Transition Test</input><br>
<input class="property_transition" type="checkbox">Property Transition Test</input><br>
<input class="property_transition" type="checkbox">Property Transition Test</input><br>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var elements = d3.selectAll(".property_transition");
    elements
        .transition()//.delay(function(d,i) { return i/elements.length *50; })
            .property("checked", true); // <== This is NOT working.
            //.each("end", function() { d3.select(this).property("checked",true); }); // <== This works!!!
</script>
```

With this script,
Chrome browser gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: elements.transition(...).property is not a
>   function

IE11 gives:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'property'

Thanks,

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to transition a binary value. You should simply set it.

Comment: I agree with you. It is for visual effects for multiple checkboxs to be checked from top to down. I like this kind of effects and, I'm sorry, but this question is mostly from my curiosity about how d3 works:)

Comment: Well `.property()` isn't something you can transition in D3, so that's the short answer :)

Comment: Thanks! You saved me from wasting time as I tend to play with my curiosity too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that `.property()` isn't something you can transition in D3, in particular it doesn't provide the respective function (as the error message you get in Chrome suggests).

In general, it doesn't really make sense to transition a binary property -- what would be the intermediate values?